# How to forward traffic between a tun device and a tap device?

Tags: linux, networking

I have an application that creates a `tun` device (think a VPN), and I've set up a `tap` device on the same host that's connected to a bridge (OVS, actually). What I'd like to do is have all traffic from that `tun` interface "route" through the `tap` device. I'm using quotes here because I know that since routing is an L3 operation I can't actually route the traffic into the `tap` interface.

Is it possible to achieve this without just making that `tap` device a `tun` device and just routing the traffic?